# Android Studio: OnClickListener grayed out and won't implement

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

First time, long time. I have tried every which way to get the OnClickListener adapter work and every time I try to implement it is grayed out using the method below. It has been occurring across mulitple different projects.

```
'
   btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        }
        });

'
```

Obviously, when I run the code it gives a nullpointerexception.

Using the code I've included below one listener, AddListener works and ViewAllListener does not. I get a nullpointerexception for the ViewAllListener again. I was following along with a tutorial and ran into the same problem. My work around was to use similar code to what I submitted below. It fixed it for that project, but now I'm having it in a completely different project. Except this time it is only with one listener and not the other. I'm stumped. For a different project I tried the " implements View.OnClickListener" attached after the extends AppCompatActivity. I still ran into the same problem with the OnClickListner grayed out and throwing a nullpointerexception when run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
`

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btn_add_horse_ll, btn_viewAll_LL;
        private final OnClickListener AddListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success " + success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };  
        private final OnClickListener ViewAllListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                ShowHorsesOnListView(dataBaseHelper);
            }
        };
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
            btn_add_horse_ll = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_horse_ll);
            btn_viewAll_LL = findViewById(R.id.btn_viewAll_LL);
            btn_add_horse_ll.setOnClickListener(AddListener);
            btn_viewAll_LL.setOnClickListener(ViewAllListener);
      }
        public OnClickListener getAddListener() {
            return AddListener;
        }
        public OnClickListener getViewAllListener(){
            return ViewAllListener;
        }

`
```

Here's the xml:

```
`  
 

    <LinearLayout>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_add_horse_ll"/>
       </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout>   
      <Button android:id="@+id/btn_viewAll_LL"/>  
      </LinearLayout>

`
```

I'm not sure what else to say or what other questions to ask, but it keeps telling me I have too much code. I have tried starting over from a new program and still end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    }
    });
```

Where have you defined `btn_add` in your code ? That is what is causing the error

Comment: The above is an example of how I tried to have the setOnCLickListener work and couldn't get it to work. I have it defined in the xml with @+id/btn_add_horse_ll and android:id="@+id/btn_viewAll_LL. When I try to implement the onClickListener for btn_viewAll_LL it is grayed out and throws a nullpointerexception. That's my problem.

Comment: then add the code which is showing the error, and not the code which you think will work, we need the exact code to determine if you are going wrong somewhere

Comment: It is the java code with the import statements and it is followed by the xml code.